# Path length in tutorial and using libraries

Tags: angularjs

I did the quickstart and immediately upon starting the tutorial section encountered path length issues as I tried to copy the "sample" project for the "hero" project.  I am using Windows 8.1.

1. What can be done at my end to alleviate the fact that the path names used by the libraries exceed 255 characters?  Windows is fairly popular and I get these errors even in putting the files in C:\ (so everyone should be getting them who uses Windows and copies the tutorials)
2. The quickstart doesn't mention how to reuse the libraries.  Since there are 16,000+ files in the downloaded libraries reusing is essential; how can this be done and why isn't it at nearly the start of the tutorial?  Imagine in chapter 6 having 100,000+ files for these trivial assignments...

Comment: This is a really annoying bug. I use a mac - but my Windows friends have needed to go in and actually change the paths until they were short enough to delete. Then clean cache, delete node modules, and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

There are now libraries to get around the 255 character limit per line on Windows